# Load Facebook comments with Ajax loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, comments

Please forgive (and correct) me if my terminology is not accurate.

Here is the link to what I am working on:  http://www.haemerd.com/index2.html

Here is a page I am trying to load with ajax: http://www.haemerd.com/glob/glob1.html

I am loading html pages into a div with the following .js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#nav li a').live('click', function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

});

The page being loaded is:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- end -->  

<div id="wrapper">
<h1>test</h1>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index2.html">welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="glob/glob1.html">glob1</a></li>
    <li><a href="glob/glob2.html">glob2</a></li>
    <li>contact</li>
    <li>terms</li>
</ul>
<div id="content"> 

<img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/files/4261/js.png">
<p>This is a test of Glob #1.</p>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://haemerd.com/glob1.html" data-width="420" data-num-posts="2"></div>

</div>

</div>

 <script>FB.XFBML.parse();</script>

</body>
```

Everything seems to work fine *except* the Facebook comments don't load. At one point I had it so it would load if I refreshed the page, but now I've broken it beyond that. :(

Answer (score 0):

See this - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

and i went http://www.haemerd.com/index2.html and in source code i didn't see any code of facebook comment

Comment: Thanks HADI. Yeah, I have been in and out of the facebook developers page. I understand clearly how the comments plugin works in its basic form. My issue occurs (I'm pretty certain) because of the ajax loading I am using.
The facebook code is not on the front page. It is on the pages I am loading with ajax. That code is shown in the last code box in the original post.

Comment: i went http://www.haemerd.com/glob/glob1.html and i am seeing fb comment is loading. Do you still on it?

Comment: Yes, it loads there without a problem, because it is not being loaded via ajax. I will restate the problem: the Facebook comments on glob1.html do not load 'when loaded through ajax', which happens on index2.html. If you go to index2.html and click glob1 or glob2, those pages will load, but the Facebook comments on them will not.